# PyQt4 and Qwt Error when opening

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pyqt4, qwt

i´m trying to do a simple plot, using PyQt4 and Qwt5. When i start the app, it shows as i expected,  but i can´t do anything, such as click or zoom for example. And if i minimize it, the plot disappears.

This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import Qt
import numpy as np
import PyQt4.Qwt5.iqt
from PyQt4.Qwt5.qplt
class SimpleData(QwtPlot):
def __init__(self):
    QwtPlot.__init__(self)

    x = np.arange(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
    p = IPlot(Curve(x, np.cos(x), Pen(Magenta,2), "cos(x)"), 
        Curve(x, np.exp(x), Pen(Red), "exp(x)", Y2),
        Axis(Right, Log),"Ejemplo de PyQt con PyQwt")

    x = x[0: -1: 10]

    p.plot(Curve(x, np.cos(x-np.pi/4), Symbol(Circle, Yellow), "circle"),
        Curve(x, np.cos(x+np.pi/4), Pen(Blue), Symbol(Square, Cyan), "Square"))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

The indentation is correct, maybe i made a mistake writting it here, but it´s ok.

Another thing, when i close the app, i get this error:

QObject::killTimers: timers cannot be stopped from another thread
[Finished in 2.6s with exit code -1073741510]

Thank you for your time and answers. I hope you can help me.